# How to scrape json data from an interactive chart?

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping, html5-canvas

I have a specific section of a [website](https://understat.com/player/2097) that I want to scrape data from and here's the screenshot of the section -
 [image]

I inspected the elements of that particular section and noticed that it's within a canvas tag. However, I also checked the source code of the website and I found that the data lies within the source code in a format I'm not familiar with. Here's a sample of that data

```
JSON.parse('\x5B\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x2232522\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2222\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22MissedShots\x22,
\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.7859999847412109\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.52\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.03867039829492569\x22,
\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Lionel\x20Messi\x22,
\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,
\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x222097\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,
\x22season\x22\x3A\x222014\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22LeftFoot\x22,
\x22match_id\x22\x3A...);
```

How do I parse through this data to give me the x,y co-ordinates of every shot from the map in the screenshot?

Comment: Are you using web-scraping in python?

Comment: The `\xNN` are hexadecimal ASCII codes. For example, `\x22` is `"`. See http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Yes, I have mostly used `Selenium`, `BeautifulSoup` , `Requests` till now

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks. Is there any commonly known, efficient way to parse through the data which uses hexadecimal codes? @Veve

Comment: I can't understand the \`x2232523`\ code. What does that signify?

Comment: `\x2232523` is `"32523`

Comment: @chitown88 That's what I figured as well. But wouldn't I be expecting it be coded as `\x22\32523\`? Why's it missing the slash throughout the script?

Comment: I'm assuming that it understands that it is in the form of \xXX. And value after is the literal value.

Comment: You can print out a loop that shows that: `import codecs

for i in range (0,100):
    try:
        value = codecs.getdecoder('unicode-escape')('\\x%.2d' %i)[0]
        print ('\\x%.2d   represents   %s' %(i, value))
    except:
        print ('\\x%.2d cannot be decoded' %i)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya the issue is with the encoding/decoding.

You can pull that string and then essentially need to ignore the escape charachters. Once you do that, you can use `json.loads()` to read that in and then can navigate the json structure.

Now I only looked quickly, but did not see the data in there to show where the plot is on the shot chart. But you can have a look to see if you can find it. The data does however have a `shotZones` key.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import codecs

url = 'https://understat.com/player/2097'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all('script')


for script in scripts:
    if 'var groupsData      = JSON.parse' in script.text:
        encoded_string = script.text
        encoded_string  = encoded_string .split("var groupsData         = JSON.parse('")[-1]
        encoded_string = encoded_string.rsplit("'),",1)[0]

        jsonStr = codecs.getdecoder('unicode-escape')(encoded_string)[0]
        jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

**Edit**

Actually I found it. Here you go:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import codecs
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize


url = 'https://understat.com/player/2097'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all('script')

    # I noticed the data was imbedded in the script tag that started with `var shotsData`
for script in scripts:
    if 'var shotsData' in script.text:

        # I store that text, then trim off the string on the ends so that 
        # it's in a valid json format
        encoded_string = script.text
        encoded_string  = encoded_string .split("JSON.parse('", 1)[-1]
        encoded_string = encoded_string.rsplit("player_info =",1)[0]
        encoded_string = encoded_string.rsplit("'),",1)[0]

        # Have it ignore the escape characters so it can decode the ascii 
        # and be able to use json.loads
        jsonStr = codecs.getdecoder('unicode-escape')(encoded_string)[0]
        jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)

df = json_normalize(jsonObj)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
                      X  ...                    xG
0    0.7859999847412109  ...   0.03867039829492569
1    0.8619999694824219  ...   0.06870150566101074
2                  0.86  ...   0.15034306049346924
3    0.8180000305175781  ...  0.045503295958042145
4    0.8690000152587891  ...   0.06531666964292526
5    0.7230000305175781  ...  0.054804932326078415
6    0.9119999694824219  ...    0.0971858948469162
7                 0.885  ...   0.11467907577753067
8     0.875999984741211  ...   0.10627452284097672
9    0.9540000152587891  ...    0.3100203275680542
10   0.8969999694824219  ...   0.12571729719638824
11   0.8959999847412109  ...   0.04122981056571007
12   0.8730000305175781  ...   0.09942527115345001
13    0.769000015258789  ...  0.025321772322058678
14                0.885  ...    0.7432776093482971
15                 0.86  ...    0.4680374562740326
16   0.7619999694824219  ...   0.05699075385928154
17    0.919000015258789  ...   0.10647356510162354
18   0.9530000305175781  ...     0.571601390838623
19   0.8280000305175781  ...   0.07561512291431427
20   0.9030000305175782  ...    0.4600500166416168
21   0.9469999694824218  ...    0.3132372796535492
22                 0.92  ...    0.2869703769683838
23   0.7659999847412109  ...   0.07576987147331238
24   0.9640000152587891  ...    0.3824153244495392
25   0.8590000152587891  ...    0.1282796859741211
26   0.9330000305175781  ...   0.42914989590644836
27   0.9230000305175782  ...    0.4968196153640747
28   0.8240000152587891  ...   0.08198583126068115
29    0.965999984741211  ...    0.4309735596179962
..                  ...  ...                   ...
843  0.9159999847412109  ...    0.4672183692455292
844  0.7430000305175781  ...   0.04068271815776825
845               0.815  ...   0.07300572842359543
846  0.8980000305175782  ...   0.06551901996135712
847  0.7680000305175781  ...  0.028392281383275986
848               0.885  ...    0.7432776093482971
849   0.875999984741211  ...    0.4060465097427368
850  0.7880000305175782  ...   0.09496577084064484
851  0.7190000152587891  ...   0.05071594566106796
852  0.7680000305175781  ...     0.090679831802845
853  0.7440000152587891  ...   0.06875557452440262
854  0.9069999694824219  ...   0.45824503898620605
855   0.850999984741211  ...   0.06454816460609436
856               0.935  ...    0.5926618576049805
857  0.9219999694824219  ...   0.16091874241828918
858                0.73  ...   0.05882067605853081
859  0.9080000305175782  ...    0.3522365391254425
860  0.8209999847412109  ...    0.1690768003463745
861   0.850999984741211  ...   0.11893663555383682
862                0.88  ...   0.11993970721960068
863  0.8119999694824219  ...   0.15579797327518463
864  0.7019999694824218  ...  0.011425728909671307
865  0.7530000305175781  ...   0.06945621967315674
866   0.850999984741211  ...   0.08273076266050339
867  0.8180000305175781  ...   0.06529481709003448
868                0.86  ...   0.10793478786945343
869  0.8190000152587891  ...  0.061923813074827194
870  0.8130000305175781  ...   0.05294585973024368
871   0.799000015258789  ...   0.06358513236045837
872  0.9019999694824219  ...    0.5841030478477478

[873 rows x 20 columns]
```

Comment: The x, y data is right there under `x22X` and `x22Y` but you already figured that out, I noticed. What `does json_normalize` do? Thanks a lot for your help though. I'll reverse-engineer your process until I understand everything you've done.

Comment: `json_normalize` just flattens it out into a table. So each row represents a single shot, with all those attributes. It isn't necessary, just more a personal preference for me as it was just easier to look at the data all in one place.

Comment: And yes, I didn't realize there were 5 different script tags in there. That first code was obviously only returning the last one it found, where as, I needed to specify specifically to get the `"var shotsData"`

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Much much appreciated!

Comment: Would this basic idea/code also work for pages whose sources which have `<script type="text/javascript">` as the script?

Comment: yes. The key is to find out which script tag has the data you want. So it does require a little investigative work at first. Usually what I do is just check to see which tag has a specific sub-string I might be interested in, then that narrows it down to where to look. Then it's just a matter of trimming off the parts of the string to make it a valid json format. Once I found the data, I noticed it had the `var shotsData` string in it, and was able to pull out that specific `<script>` tag. The thing is, it doesn't always have the data there. some sites works, some dont. Does that make sense?

Comment: And USUALLY, it's not a unicode decode type of issue. This was a new one for me.

Comment: Yes absolutely, that makes sense. I investigated the source myself and did find all the data right there. I'll just have to change the string `var...` part and the working of the loop. I was only wondering if the javascript part of the script makes any difference since this one didn't have anything similar and I've heard that Javascript is a bit more difficult to scrape. Thanks again for your help! And no, this new site isn't encoded so no worries

Comment: Oh ya ya! Sometimes it won't even have the `type` part, so that's why I usually just look for strictly `<script>` tags only. It usually will pull up 20 - 40 elements, and most of them are just of no interest to get the data you want. But cool, looks like you're well on your way then. And ya, it's actually not TOO difficult once you figure it out. some just a lot harder than others, just depends