# Scraping JSON data from interactive chart - Extra data error `json.load()`

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to figure out how to scrape the web data using this post as a reference: [How to scrape json data from an interactive chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55703531/how-to-scrape-json-data-from-an-interactive-chart)

I have gotten the JSON Chart data from the website, but I am having difficulty in the final step with loading the file using `json.load()`. I keep getting the error: `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 67193 (char 67192)`

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import requests
    import json
    import codecs
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQaftrT4JJh6dqfFHaUuxiOE5CiFDTt2YIbiJe9sATHQrBILnfUVpSnDTKg26yTgmZKci4NVxtsByD7/pubchart?oid=1258306542&format=interactive"
    response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="html.parser")
    scripts = soup.find_all('script')[1]
    
    for script in scripts:
        if 'chartJson' in script:
            encoded_string = script
            encoded_string = encoded_string.split("'chartJson': '",1)[-1]
            encoded_string = encoded_string.split("', 'fallbackUri'",1)[0]
            jsonStr = codecs.getdecoder('unicode-escape')(encoded_string)[0]
            jsonStr = jsonStr.split(',\\"parsedNumHeaders\\":1',1)[0]
            jsonStr = jsonStr.split('"rows":',1)[1]
            jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

Comment: The data does not seems to be valid JSON. The error indicates that there is valid JSON until character 67192. Check the response from there!

Comment: How would I go about finding out which character is the one giving me an error? 67,000 characters is a lot and the TraceBack doesn't tell you which character either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could paste the `jsonStr` in to [here](https://jsonlint.com/) to find the issue. This code worked for me though. you split on the `"rows"` key but there was another `"cols"` key in that level. They're is then also an extra comma at the end.

`jsonStr = codecs.getdecoder('unicode-escape')(encoded_string)[0]` also didn't take care of the unicode escapes, so I added `jsonStr = jsonStr.encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape')`

```
import requests
import json
import codecs
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import unicodedata

url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQaftrT4JJh6dqfFHaUuxiOE5CiFDTt2YIbiJe9sATHQrBILnfUVpSnDTKg26yTgmZKci4NVxtsByD7/pubchart?oid=1258306542&format=interactive"
response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="html.parser")
scripts = soup.find_all('script')[1]

for script in scripts:
    if 'chartJson' in script:
        encoded_string = script
        encoded_string = encoded_string.split("'chartJson': '",1)[-1]
        encoded_string = encoded_string.split("', 'fallbackUri'",1)[0]
        jsonStr = codecs.getdecoder('unicode-escape')(encoded_string)[0]
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split(',\\"parsedNumHeaders\\":1',1)[0]
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split('"rows":',1)[1]
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split('"cols":',1)[0].rstrip(',')
        jsonStr = jsonStr.encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape')
        jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is my first time trying to webscrape something and your code was really easy to follow so thank you.

Comment: webscraping is fun. They're not all as tricky as these embeded json in the scripts (I hate those!!)